# scrapy speed processing with proxies

Tags: performance, proxy, scrapy

I can't figure out the best settings to speed up my scraping process with scrapy framework.

1. I am scraping a unique website
2. I am using 400 proxies

What I would like to do is launching 400 simultaneous requests (the scraped website can easily handle it) and wait a random time (let's say between 5 and 10 seconds to avoid being banned).

I have created a ProxyMiddleware which gives each request the less used proxy and it works fine, I also have set CONCURRENT_ITEMS to a very high amount (I got a very powerfull server)

If I correctly understand [scrapy settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) I have to set :

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 400
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0
```

because if I set DOWNLOAD_DELAY to something higher than 0, my requests won't execute concurrently because they are hitting same website

So what I have done is write :

```
time.sleep(float("{0:.2f}".format(random.uniform(5,10))))
```

inside my parse function, but as I am a newbie in python, I wonder :

1. Is the time.sleep affecting the entire scraping process or only the parse function where it is ?
2. Is there a way to configure scrapy with available settings to achieve my goal ?
3. How can I understand multi-threading concept if this concept exists in scrapy to improve my spider performance ?

Comment: FYI, internally Scrapy uses [`reactor.callLater()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.callLater.html) for the delayed requests, see [source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/9af61d5df673b9b9d7658c78a2dc6a017459cdf9/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L122-129).

Comment: 1) Yes it affects entire process since scrapy works in a single thread (which is twisted reactor) and by sleeping in parse, your completely stopping the process.
2) CONCURRENCY limits works regardless of domain.
3) See twisted tutorials.